# How to have my child view not capture clicks outside its bounds?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am extending a `ListFragment` in which I override `onViewCreated` to add a child view on top of the list. This child view is intended to be a small badge that the user can click on to refresh the list.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ListUpdateIndicator badge = new ListUpdateIndicator(getActivity());
    badge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Badge clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
    ((ViewGroup) view).addView(badge);
}
```

My `ListUpdateIndicator` view is a `LinearLayout` defined like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/some_icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Refresh"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The view shows up fine, but clicking anywhere on the screen will be caught by the badge view click listener. I can't scroll my list.

How can I capture clicks only on the child view and "pass through" clicks outside its bounds to the parent (the list in this case)?

I thought that specifying wrap_content as the width/height would make my child view only take the space it needs. It seems like it overlays the entire screen instead.

Comment: Why not add `ListUpdateIndicator` as the header of the `ListView` instead?

Comment: It's essentially just like Facebook's "10 New Stories". My goal is to have this view overlap the list at all times regardless of the scroll position. Also, I'm trying to make it generic enough to be able to re-use it as docked to the bottom of a list in another design.

Comment: One easy trick might be to have a custom `FrameLayout` where the `ListView` is the first child and `ListUpdateIndicator` is second.